# ValueError: Field doesn't exists [Odoo 12]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to get a client_order_ref from a sale order, from the account.invoice module. I don't know why it says that the field doesn't exits, and the field it's defined. Please help me

**Python code**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    client_order_ref = fields.Char(string="Client Order Ref", compute="get_client_from_sale_order")

    @api.depends('name')
    def get_client_from_sale_order(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        for rec in self:
            sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(
                [('name', '=', rec.origin)]
            )

            rec.client_order_ref = sale_order.client_order_ref
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="invoice_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account_invoice_tree_inherit</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
                <field name="client_order_ref"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

TRACEBACK

> Error: Odoo Server Error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1128, in
> _validate_fields
> check(self)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 351, in _check_xml
> self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 1138, in postprocess_and_fields
> self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 568, in raise_view_error
> raise ValueError(message) ValueError: Field `client_order_ref` does not exist
>
> Error context: View `account_invoice_tree_inherit` [view_id: 1311,
> xml_id: cloudpiles_custom.invoice_tree, model: account.invoice,
> parent_id: 681]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
> self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 663, in
> _tag_record
> record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3883, in
> _load_records
> data['record']._load_records_write(data['values'])   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 1542, in _load_records_write
> super(View, self)._load_records_write(values)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3821, in
> _load_records_write
> self.write(values)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 445, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3392, in write
> fields[0].determine_inverse(records)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1200, in
> determine_inverse
> getattr(records, self.inverse)()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 275, in _inverse_arch
> view.write(data)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 445, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3366, in write
> self._write(store_vals)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3502, in _write
> self._validate_fields(vals)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1132, in
> *validate_fields
> raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (*("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e))) odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error
> while validating constraint\n\nField `client_order_ref` does not
> exist\n\nError context:\nView
> `account_invoice_tree_inherit`\n[view_id: 1311, xml_id:
> cloudpiles_custom.invoice_tree, model: account.invoice, parent_id:
> 681]', None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 656, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in
> _handle_exception
> raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in
> reraise
> raise value   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 967, in
> call_button
> action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 955, in _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
> return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line
> 75, in check_and_log
> return method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line
> 628, in button_immediate_upgrade
> return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py",
> line 562, in _button_immediate_function
> modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in
> new
> odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in
> load_modules
> force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in
> load_marked_modules
> perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in
> load_module_graph
> load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in
> load_data
> tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in
> convert_file
> convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 865, in
> convert_xml_import
> obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 764, in parse
> exc_info[2]   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in
> reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
> self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 663, in
> _tag_record
> record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')   File
> "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3883, in
> _load_records
> data['record']._load_records_write(data['values'])   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 1542, in _load_records_write
> super(View, self)._load_records_write(values)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3821, in
> _load_records_write
> self.write(values)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 445, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3392, in write
> fields[0].determine_inverse(records)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1200, in
> determine_inverse
> getattr(records, self.inverse)()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 275, in _inverse_arch
> view.write(data)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py",
> line 445, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3366, in write
> self._write(store_vals)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3502, in _write
> self._validate_fields(vals)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1132, in
> *validate_fields
> raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (*("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e))) odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error
> while validating constraint
>
> Field `client_order_ref` does not exist
>
> Error context: View `account_invoice_tree_inherit` [view_id: 1311,
> xml_id: cloudpiles_custom.invoice_tree, model: account.invoice,
> parent_id: 681] None" while parsing
> /opt/odoo/auto/addons/cloudpiles_custom/views/account_invoice_view.xml:3,
> near 
> account_invoice_tree_inherit
> account.invoice

Comment: Have you checked if that specific python file (model) actually gets loaded?

Comment: Check if sale_order is not false
`if sale_order:` then assigned `rec.client_order_ref = sale_order.client_order_ref` also use else `rec.client_order_ref = False` as an assignment is mandatory at least it is in odoo 13

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you forgot an important point about inheritance from odoo's models...
when you added a new field on existing model in odoo's modules ,first of all you have to upgrading your module with command, not with odoo interface...
just run this command: `./odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf -d data_base_name -u module_name`
I hope this will help you.